# Inline stylings within SVG elements not applied when using data URI

Tags: css, svg, data-uri

I'm encountering an issue with inline styles within an SVG element not being respected when I convert the SVG to a data URI and embed it as an image. Everything works and I can render the svg and the images after converting to the URI but stylings does not work.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="30 100 700 300" style="enable-background:new 0 0 750 500;" xml:space="preserve">
   <g>
     <image style="display: none;" xlink:href="some-image-link"></image>
   </g>
 </svg>
```

Specifically, the display: block; style on the  element is not working when I use the data URI method. The image is displayed even though it should be hidden.

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,'. base64_encode(svg_string) .'"/>
```

and this the how I convert the SVG.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah sorry forgot to change that part while writing the example html. @RobertLongson

Comment: That is why we ask for a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it makes you check your own code.

Comment: Keep in mind data urls need to be self-contained. So you also need to convert image references to data URLs otherwise the `<image>` within the svg  won't be displayed. See [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/KKEoRjN)

Comment: Thanks for the tip but the images within the SVG are successfully loading and visible even if I don't convert them to data URIs. My specific problem is that inline styles defined on elements within the SVG (like display: none; on the <image> tag) are not being applied when the entire SVG is converted to a data URI. @herrstrietzel

Comment: It should be the other way round: style - no problem; refs inside a base64  -no way. Please add a reproducible example. You may use a service like plnkr or codesandbox to emulate a filesystem. See [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/uu7yzkoUHp7NyT3S?open=lib%2Findex.html&preview). Please inspect the final output in dev tools. Your base64 encoding function may also invalidate css (e.g due to escaping issues)